# Как делается фронтенд для Java-приложений?

Tags: java, архитектура, frontend

Я столкнулся с тем, что не понимаю, как обычно реализуется фронт для Java-приложения. У меня есть несколько предположений о том, как это может быть:

1. Фронт делается при помощи JSP, thymeleaf или других Java-фреймворков для фронтенда, т.е. всё делается исключительно на мощностях Java.
2. На Java-сервере делается только бэкенд, который отдаёт данные для отрисовки, но не отрисовывает их сам *(т.е. бэкенд на Java, а фронт делается отдельно в другом, более подходящем для этого приложении)*.

Я понимаю, что можно сделать и так и так. Но интересует то, как это делается обычно, в том числе для крупных проектов.

Comment: Не делать фронтенд на Java - что имеется в виду?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець я сделаю веб-приложение на java, сделаю ему rest api. А веб-разработчики поднимут сайт на PHP, который будет дёргать моё приложение и получать все данные через json. Т.е. весь фронт на стороне веб-разработчиков.

Comment: ну так вам меньше работы, выбирайте этот вариант )))))

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець ну во-первых денег жалко. Java я на каком-то достаточном уровне знаю. А веб знаю только на уровне унылого табличного html. А во-вторых интересует то, как обычно это делается "по правилам". Амазон, например, на java сделан, но фронт у них отрисовывается отдельным php-сервером или при помощи java? Вот это интересно.

Comment: Ну, РНР я не знаю, давно юзал, а thymeleaf и подобные шаблонизаторы вроде рулят сейчас

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с того что знание java для фронта не совсем то что нужно. Если у вас верстка унылая и табличная то сообственно вам фреймворк мало чем помогут, максимально вы получите жалкое подобие ui на ваш бек.

Для фронта вам нужно изучить html css JavaScript это программа минимум. По максимуму вы поднимите react/angular/vue фронт приложение с java http сервером на бекенде (не важно какой) который будет обрабатывать ваши запросы с ui. Вот почему вам говорят что jsp устарела.

**Updated**.

Ваш первый вариант он устарел. Не стану говорить что его нет говорю лишь о том что устарел. Почему устарел, потому что современные фронтенд фреймворки дают большую гибкость независимость скорость разработки. В нынешних реалиях java,c# ушли на бек что не есть плохо. В микросервисной архитектуре это ещё лучше. Вы можете реализовать поставщика на чём угодно и делать ui также для чего угодно не привязываясь к платформе языку и прочему, достаточно лишь поддерживать стандартные протоколы общения. Вот почему делать монолит из java,c# это вчерашний день. И вообще на сегодняшний день все строят свои крупные проекты разбив на десятки и более мелких частей каждую из которых можно безболезненно быстро заменить с поддержкой протоколов. Rest/swagger/openapi и остальные паттерны.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Дело в том, что я рассматриваю возможность заказать вёрстку на стороне, а не делать самому. Вот и остаются варианты: либо потом эту вёрстку самому обрабатывать в java (это в моей компетенции), либо сказать тем, кто будет делать вёрстку, также сделать и php, а на мне останется только rest сервис.

Comment: Ну вы понимаете что java бек как и php в современных реалиях. Нужен фронт который будет рендерить страницу для ui. И тут нужен желательно typescript.

Comment: Был бы признателен, если бы вы отредактировали свой ответ (я уточнил свой вопрос насколько это возможно)

Comment: Обновил добавил вам объяснения